# Loop through JSON in ionic

Tags: json, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Is there a way to loop through a JSON like below in ionic 3

```
[
 {
   "date": "28/09/2017 08:03",
   "data": {
     "1": 10,
     "2": 0
   }
},
{
   "date": "28/09/2017 08:04",
   "data": {
    "1": 0,
    "2": 5
   }
}
]
```

I have tried to loop through but to no avail. This is the latest i have tried but not working

```
this.data = returnedJson;

  for (let reportData of this.data.data) {
        console.log("Our Data : " + reportData);
    }
```

and

```
  for (let reportData in this.data.data) {
        console.log("Our Data : " + reportData);
    }
```

Comment: `this.data` is the array you need to loop through not `this.data.data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (const item of this.data) {
    console.log("Our Data : " + item.data);
}
```

Comment: I can loop through the dates now from the cod you gave  but unable to get the data out.  
    `item.data`  return Objects instead o the numbers in it

Comment: Oh! i get it. Just lopped through the array and it worked